# How do you publish a bot using Bot Builder SDK for .NET to Azure without using the Bot Service first?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, botframework

I have created a bot using the Bot Builder SDK for .NET using visual studio.  However, there are no instructions on to publish the bot to Azure without using the Bot Service.

is this even possible or do we need use the bot service first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bot Framework naming is a bit confusing.

There are two ways to start:

- [Create a Bot with Bot service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-quickstart)
- [Create a Bot with Bot Builder (.NET / Node.js)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart)

Both these options are Web Apps with Bot Builder SDK. The first option will generate the code (based on bot templates), publish to Azure and register to Bot Channels; all done automatically for you. The second option gives you more flexibility where you write your own code as ASP.NET Web App (or Node.js), publish and register will need to be done manually.

When you are using Bot Builder SDK for .NET; after the [get started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart) page, the next thing is to simply publish your web application project to Azure (or AWS which ever). There are so many ways to do this, but in Visual Studio; just right-click on your Bot project, select [Publish to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet#create-and-publish-the-web-app) (might need some VS add-on). Once your Bot is in the cloud (Azure). You'll need to [Register your Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-quickstart-registration) and the messaging endpoint will be your new Bot Web App in Azure *(https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/messages)*

Finally, make sure you update the **Microsoft App ID** and **Microsoft App Password** in your code and republish your Bot application again. Now you can test and configure channels to talk to your bot.